# Right version of Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, hp

My parents have just given my their old laptop; it has a jawdropping 500MB of RAM and a 1.4 ghz processor. 
Is there a version of ubuntu that would function well on it?

Cheers

Comment: if you want to browse the internet you will need more ram, 1gb more at least.

Comment: Nothing. It will be terribly slow. Even Xubuntu is slow on that. Use XP (with nLite) or even some older Windows would work. Yeah I know, we are on AU, but really, that's a viable option for you.

Answer (score 0):

It meets the minimal requirements for both Xubuntu and Lubuntu. Xubuntu has slightly more eye candy, Lubuntu is slightly lighter. Still, they're pretty close, so unless you have a particular preference for lxde over xfce, I would try Xubuntu and go straight for a super-lightweight distro like Puppy Linux if Xubuntu turns out to be too heavy.

Comment: I Strongly Recommend Xubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Lubuntu, but keep in mind that you'd need to increase your RAM as much as possible (at least to 1GB).

Comment: As long as he can find a suitable memory card on the market)

Comment: @Pavel, of course.